# Displaying Facebook Avatar in Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, avatar

I've been trying to get the bengott:avatar package from atmosphere.js to work with Facebook but have not been able to do so. When I use `{{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}`it only seems to display a gray circle with no picture inside.

Other calls such as `{{currentUser.profile.name}}`work perfectly fine.

How can I successfully display an avatar with or without the bengott:avatar package?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead, you don't need an access token or anything special to get their profile picture, just their facebook user id.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if (options.profile) {
        options.profile.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
        user.profile = options.profile;
    }
    return user;
});
```

Comment: what handlebars would I need to actually display the avatar on the page? would it be something like {{currentUser.profile.picture}} ?

Answer (score 1):

I use a helper function based off of the Facebook ID of the user to grab the image on the server. Hope this helps.

```
userPicHelper: function() {
    if (this.profile) {
        var id = this.profile.facebookId;
        var img = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?type=square&height=160&width=160';
        return img;
    }
},
```

In the template you would use the helper like this:

```
<img src="{{userPicHelper}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Once the image is grabbed from the server, what handlebars do I use to actually display the image? I've tried {{currentUser.profile.picture}} and all sorts of variations of this but it doesn't work.